# category page with static block not listing products

Tags: magento-1.9, catalog, static-block, ce-1.9.3.1

I'm using magento 1.9 with molly theme. I added sub-category static blocks on category pages(reference:https://www.templatemonster.com/help/magento-listing-sub-categories-on-a-category-page.html#gref). I have selected the display option for category as ' static and products '

For some reason, one category page shows all products but another doesn't show any or only 1 or 2 products.

Below are the links to refer:

http://dcgears.com.sg/power.html

http://dcgears.com.sg/console-server/console-server-by-port.html

http://dcgears.com.sg/console-server.html

I have checked the products are added in desired category also did reindexing after adding products and cache is disabled.

Please help to resolve this issue.

Comment: What is the code that you have inserted in your cms page to display a category ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check if Is Anchor -YES for those categories that are not showing products.

The first thing I would do is to compare your power.html (because this seems to be the one that is working correctly) category against the ones that are not working.

'catalog/layer' is for layered navigation, to use layered navigation your categories need to be Is Anchor -> Yes.

Answer (score 1):

You need to ensure the following:

1) the product is assigned to a category

2) the product is assigned to a store view.

3) the product status `is In Stock`

4) the product has a qty assigned

5) Product status should not be disable.

6) product visibility is set to `catalog-search`

Once this has been done, flush the store cache and do reindexing the product will appear.

Comment: I have checked the above points but still no luck. I think the code given for subcategory listing in https://www.templatemonster.com/help/magento-listing-sub-categories-on-a-category-page.html is wrong, because if i change the code, it works fine.